# Read a continuously updated file and wait for new data to be written to the file in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I have a log file and I want to write a program in C to read that log file and wait for new data if EOF is reached.
I do not want to use `tail -f` in my code.
I tried the following code but it is not working:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PATH "/home/sanket/demo.txt"

int main(void)
{
        FILE * fp;
    int fd;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read1;
    int notify_fd;
    int wd,length ,i=0;
    char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];

    fp = fopen(PATH, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    fd = fileno(fp);
    while (1)
    {
            read1 = getline(&line, &len, fp);
            if(read1 != -1)
                    printf("%s",line);
            else
            {
                    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_DATA);
            }
    }

    if (line)
            free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474232/how-to-loop-through-only-active-file-descriptors-from-fd-set-result-from-select)

Comment: You dont need to seek when you reach end of file, just sleep and read again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you reach the first end of file, the input stream flag for EOF is set.  That has to be cleared before you can resume operations (`clearerr(fp)`).  You should normally sleep, too.  (Using `lseek()` on the file descriptor associated with the stream won't help.)

Here's a program based on your code — I had to change the value of PATH (which isn't a particularly good name):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PATH "demo.txt"

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    fp = fopen(PATH, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror(PATH);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        if (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1)
            printf("%s",line);
        else
        {
            printf("EOF\n");
            sleep(1);
            clearerr(fp);
        }
    }

    if (line)
        free(line);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If you have a program that generates data to a file, you can test with it.  I have a program `dribbler` that does that:

```
$ dribbler -f demo.txt -s 1.5 -r 0.5 &
[1] 20678
$ cat demo.txt
0: message written to file
1: message written to file
2: message written to file
$ tail11
0: message written to file
1: message written to file
2: message written to file
3: message written to file
4: message written to file
5: message written to file
EOF
6: message written to file
EOF
EOF
7: message written to file
EOF
8: message written to file
EOF
EOF
9: message written to file
EOF
10: message written to file
EOF
11: message written to file
EOF
EOF
^C
$
```

The options to `dribbler` are:

```
Usage: dribbler [-hlntV][-s nap.time][-r std.dev][-f outfile][-i infile][-m message][-o openstr][-F format]
  -V           Print version information and exit
  -f outfile   Write to named file (dribbler.out)
  -h           Print this help message and exit
  -i infile    Read lines from input file
  -l           Loop back to start of input file on EOF
  -m message   Write message on each line of output
  -n           Number lines read from input file
  -o openstr   Flags passed to fopen() (a+)
  -s nap.time  Sleep for given interval between writes (1.000 second)
  -r std.dev   Randomize the time (Gaussian around nap.time with std.dev)
  -t           Write to standard output instead of file
  -F format    Printf format to use instead of %zu
```

So, it was writing to the file `demo.txt` at a mean time of 1.5 seconds, with a Gaussian random distribution with 0.5 seconds standard deviation.
That's why there were sometimes 2 `EOF` messsages between successive lines of output.

Comment: I have made changes according to your code... and running that binary......writing manually in that file but my program is unable to read updated data

Comment: That's sad!  I tested on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2, using GCC 7.2.0 as the compiler.  I'm confident that it would work on Linux and other Unix-based platforms (though I've not formally tested this code on any other platform today).  What platform are you working on?  What does your modified code look like?  (You could add it to the question if necessary — do not destroy what's already there, though.) . It's a bit hard to guess what you've done wrong, but I guess that you have done something wrong, or you're working on an esoteric platform where this does not work.

Comment: One way you can run into problems is if the program(s) writing to the file truncate it rather than always appending.  There may be other ways too.

Comment: when i am appending to file with echo command it is working but when writing that file with vim editor its not working

Comment: That sounds plausible.  When you write with `vim`, is the file always longer than it was before you edited it?  If not, then the program won't spot the changed material.  But then, too, neither would `tail -f` (probably).  It would be possible to revise the program so that if the file was shorter than it was when EOF was last detected, then the program could restart reading at the beginning.  There presumably isn't a benefit to seeking to the new shorter end position as there's nothing to read after it — unless there's also a separate (non-`vim`) process appending to the file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `getline` works fine on Linux (with the above code) would there be any downside to using a *character oriented* approach like `fgetc` instead of `getline` (other than more trips through the `while` loop before sleeping)? Essentially the same setup, but with a `fgetc / putchar` approach? (and maybe a flag to exit on two (or some number) of consecutive `EOF`s)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: there's a marginal performance penalty, usually offset by the fact that the code gets to sleep periodically.  If it doesn't sleep periodically, it means the file is growing about as fast as it can be read.  But there's very little downside to a character-by-character approach.  The key trick is `clearerr()` — and the secondary trick is a suitable sleep (not necessarily a whole second — it could be more or less time).  The rest is incidental.